# Windows PUSHD UNC Path

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file that needs to connect a remote server directory and then run an executable on a file located in the mapped drive.

This is how I currently have my batch file set up:

```
@echo off
pushd \\oma-entfs-004\APS\wwwroot\tuition\
c:\PDFtk\bin\pdftk.exe uploads/Educational_Assistance_Request_Form_North_America.pdf fill_form uploads/1413993009.fdf output uploads/x.pdf need_appearances
popd
```

I assume that uploads/ should know that its within the mapped drive set by `pushd`?

For some reason nothing happens when this batch file runs but if I map the drive manually and pass it in there, it works fine.

Comment: Hard to believe that "nothing happens". Try leaving echo on, check the `errorlevel` set by the executable call, watch what happens with Process Monitor and look for errors, etc.

Comment: setlocal enableextensions

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
net use X: \\oma-entfs-004\APS
pushd X:\wwwroot\tuition\
c:\PDFtk\bin\pdftk.exe uploads/Educational_Assistance_Request_Form_North_America.pdf fill_form uploads/1413993009.fdf output uploads/x.pdf need_appearances
popd
```

Does the mapping require user/password?

[According to this](http://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html) pushd should support UNC (unlike `CD`):

> **UNC Network paths** When a UNC path is specified, PUSHD will create a temporary drive map and will then use that new drive.  The temporary
>   drive letters are allocated in reverse alphabetical order, so if Z: is
>   free it will be used first.

and my tests against localhost worked.

Comment: I tried it and it didnt seem to work; now I'm trying to figure out how to determine if this file is even being executed. I am doing it from PHP `$current = getcwd() . '\\uploads\\';
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$WshShell->exec($current.'makePDF.bat ' .$fdf_file.' '.$newPDF); `

Is there an easy way to have the batch file write to a log so I know if its being run?

Comment: The mapping does not require a user/password

Answer (score 0):

```
\\serenity\c$>
```

And I got that as current directory by this command.

```
C:\Users\User>start /d \\serenity\c$ cmd /k
```

and setting this registry key

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor

DisableUNCCheck = DWord = 1
```

so perhaps eith of these may work

**[changed forward slash to backslash]**

```
c:\PDFtk\bin\pdftk.exe \\oma-entfs-004\APS\wwwroot\tuition\uploads\Educational_Assistance_Request_Form_North_America.pdf fill_form uploads/1413993009.fdf output uploads/x.pdf need_appearances
```

or

```
start /d \\oma-entfs-004\APS\wwwroot\tuition\ cmd /k c:\PDFtk\bin\pdftk.exe  uploads\Educational_Assistance_Request_Form_North_America.pdf fill_form uploads/1413993009.fdf output uploads/x.pdf need_appearances
```

To log, change echo off to echo on and run the batch like so `cmd /k c:\somefolder\batch.bat>log.txt`

Answer (score -1):

Windows CMD cannot have a current directory which is a network path. Full stop.

You should rewrite your script to use full paths and not reference the current directory.

If that's not possible you will have to map a drive letter using `NET USE`

Comment: This really isn't answering the question. The `pushd` command will make a temporary drive mapping if given a UNC path - so the code as written ought to work.

Comment: @AndrewMedico, only if you `setlocal enableextensions`.